# Selecting Mitsuba Renderer Crashes Blender

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render an animation using Mitsuba in Blender on a computer running Ubuntu 14.04. However, every time I try to select Mitsuba as the render engine, Blender instantly crashes. Trying to export a Mitsuba XML also causes a similar behavior. I though that the executable path was the problem, but when I set that path to `/usr/bin/mitsuba`, it still crashes. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using [this developer build](https://app.box.com/s/dfifcpka9jd76rx1n053s7k75lf7su20), seems to solve the issue on my machine. More information can be found [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?270335-Addon-Mitsuba-Blender-Plugin-(26-Nov-15)). I had the same problem.

Also, the path should be `/usr/bin` and not `/usr/bin/mitsuba`

Answer (score 1):

I've been annoyed by this problem for a long time and today I finally know the solution!

When execute blender in terminal and select mitsuba, blender will crash, and you will see blender has just found `mitsuba.so` and met the problem: `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread`.

It is all because of the version mismatch of python interpreter. The lib `mitsuba.so` you installed from deb file does't match the python interpreter in your system. So you have to compile the mitsuba source code and get a new `mitsuba.so` and replace the original one.